# Dreaded: intellij no executable code found at line error

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I know this has been asked a bunch of times here but I've followed every solution to the letter multiple times and this still happens.

I have a Java project and imported a Mavin pom.xml file to create the IntelliJ project.  Everything compiles fine, just can't debug.

What I've I've tried so far:

- Delete the .idea folder and start again from the pom.xml
- Invalidated Cache/ - Restarted multiple times
- Added the -g to the Javac compile commands
- Rebuilt - the project multiple times
- Deleted the class files and rebuilt
- Ensured the project bytecode versions are all the same    (1.8)

Jar is here:
\nodebox\dist\lib\nodebox.jar

Classes are here:
\nodebox\target\classes\nodebox

Still no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, as usual, try something for 4 hours then post a qestion here and find the answer 5 mins later.  Couldn't get any configs working and saw you can right click on a class containing a main function and debug from there, intelliJ will create a run config using that class.  This magically works, even if I pick the generated config without right clicking on the class